# mysql_fetch_array with dates separated

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to loop through MySQL results and return same dates & agents in a separate .  The table containing this data has the number of tickets each agent works on a specific day.  Each group of dates should be separated by a blank row in the table.  Below is the code I am working with.  I believe I have to do a foreach, but not sure how to get it working.

Here is a screenshot to a final table layout I am looking to achieve.

[image]

```
    if($res && mysql_num_rows($res))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
if ($row['total_updated'] > 0) {
print   "<tr>";
print       "<td align=center>" . $row['date_added'] . "</td>";
print       "<td nowrap>" . $row['agent'] . "</td>";
print       "<td nowrap>" . $row['agent_location'] . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['total_updated']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['total_notes']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['total_closed']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app1_updated']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app1_notes']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app1_closed']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app2_updated']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app2_notes']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app2_closed']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app3_updated']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app3_notes']) . "</td>";
print       "<td align=center>" . number_format($row['ticket_app3_closed']) . "</td>";
print   "</tr>";
    }
        }
}
print   "</table>";
```

Comment: so... slap some `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags in there. We have no idea what your expected layout is, so that's the best you're going to get.

Comment: yeah^^ pls add more infos about what should be the endresult and a question

Comment: Added a screenshot of how I'd like the final table output to look.  Sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort your results by date_added you don't need any foreach, just compare previous date with current one:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    if (!isset($lastdate))
        $lastdate = $row['date_added'];
    if ($lastdate != $row['date_added']) {
         ?><tr><td colspan="15">---blank line---</td></tr> <?php
    }
    //paste all of your prints here
    $lastdate = $row['date_added'];
}
```